# ActivityIndicator with setTimeout doesnt work - react native expo

Tags: react-native, fetch, settimeout, loading, activity-indicator

I'm in my very first step in creating my app, and I want to implement a loading spinner on screen while fetching for data. this issue on the signUp/signIn screens, when user type his details to log in to the application. when he press on log in, i want to run the loading spinner, till the timer end. 
please check the code below, when the loading appear on the screen it's for about a second, and then continue to the next screen, Although I set the timer to 30000 ms :

```
import {  Text, View, ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native';

const LoginScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

 const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

 const _onLoginPressed = () => {
    setIsLoading(true);


    const user = {
      Email: email.value,
      PasswordTourist: password.value
    };


    fetch(apiUrl, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(user),
      headers: new Headers({
        'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
      })

    })
      .then(res => {
        return res.json()
      })
      .then(
        (result) => {
          closeActivityIndicator();
        const profile = result;

          if(profile.Email === null || profile.PasswordTourist === null){
          ...code....
            setIsLoading(false)
          }
          else{

              navigation.navigate('Dashboard', { profile: profile })

          }

        },
        (error) => {
          console.warn("err post=", error);
        });
     }
  };

const closeActivityIndicator = async => setTimeout(() => {setIsLoading(false)}, 30000)

return (
    <Background>
      code......
      {isLoading && <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#fff" />}
code....
 </Background>
)
```

Comment: Instead of setTimeout, call setIsLoading(false) directly inside the .then block so the Loader will go away as son you have the data. Also make sure to call setIsLoading(false) inside the .catch block so user wont be stuck in loading state in case the API call failed.

Comment: thx Hisham! but i want to hold the screen with the loading spinner for few seconds, and with your suggestion the spinner will be like 1 or less sconds on the screen. any idea how i figure it out to have that for more seconds on the screen?

Comment: Instead of calling closeActivityIndicator function, try calling the setTimeout from the then code block it self and see if that fixes. Just to make sure that setTimeout is not called while you initialise the closeActivityIndicator function itself.